# Dynamic pattern for vim highlight

Tags: vim

In the vim help, there is a suggestion to use highlight groups for highlighting text greater than the `textwidth`:

> Another example, which highlights all characters in virtual column
>   72 and more: 
>   
>   `:highlight rightMargin term=bold ctermfg=blue guifg=blue 
>   :match rightMargin /.\%>72v/`

I would like this to always reflect the value of `texwidth` setup. Something like:

`match rightMargin /%\=&textwidthv.*/`

But this doesn't give me what is expected. Can you  help me to parameterize OverLength with the actual value of `textwitdh`.

NB:  I plan to put this in a `filetype` autocommand block , inside which,  there would be a set to  `textwidth` option and redefinition of the `rightMargin` highlight group.

I realize that this parameterization will not save me any lines of code, but I just want to know if this is possible at all in vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
call matchadd('rightMargin', '\%'. &tw .'v')
```

You should probably put this in a `ftplugin` (see `:help ftplugin`) rather than an `autocmd`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on ftplugin too!

Comment: Multiple suggestions here along the same lines: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_long_lines